# Adding Nodejs to Django

Tags: node.js, django

I hope this post doesn't get removed for not being specific enough but I am trying to get regular barcodes read in a Django project and I am not finding a way to do it that matches my ability to implement it in the time that I have allotted. I see a lot of ways to do it using Nodejs and I really don't want to add another framework for just this one function but I am not seeing any other way to do it that has good browser support. My specific question is: is this a bad route to take or is it common practice to add another framework like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a framework (Django) against a language (NodeJS), check for Python libraries, for sure you can find some e.g. OpenCV.

Comment: But the barcade reading will only be available on the front end so python cannot help me here. Unless I am misunderstanding?

Comment: If you are talking about barcode reading then you need a JS library not nodeJS as NodeJS is a server side language, if you have a barcode scanner, you don’t need to do anything as the input will be received as if it is coming from a keyboard.

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar enough with Node.js at the moment to know what I am asking. I understand now and have found my solution to just use this CDN here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-barcode-reader

Comment: Exactly, a JS package